# R reshape matrix into multidimensional array to be used in convolutional neural network training

Tags: arrays, r, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm terribly stuck at reshaping a matrix into multidimensional array to be used in convolutional neural network training.

Here's a sample 2x16 matrix (the actual matrix will be around 11000x1024)

```
two_samples <- structure(c(257, 17, 258, 18, 65795, 19, 65796, 20, 261, 21,
262, 22, 65799, 23, 65800, 24, 9, 25, 10, 26, 65547, 27, 65548, 
28, 13, 29, 14, 30, 65551, 31, 65552, 32), .Dim = c(2L, 16L))
two_samples
#>      [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4] [,5] [,6]  [,7]  [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#> [1,]  257  258 65795 65796  261  262 65799 65800    9    10 65547 65548
#> [2,]   17   18    19    20   21   22    23    24   25    26    27    28
#>      [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
#> [1,]    13    14 65551 65552
#> [2,]    29    30    31    32
```

Here, each row is one sample and I would like to represent each sample as if it's color image. And I would like to arrange the data such that it can be used with Keras/Tensorflow for CNN training.

Generating RGB data from decimal numbers is done via `bitwAnd()` and `bitwShiftR()` functions. I run the commands below to generate RGB from the matrix. Afterwards I used `dim()` for array and `aperm()` to reshape the array:

```
mat_r <- bitwAnd(bitwShiftR(t(two_samples),16), 255)
mat_g <- bitwAnd(bitwShiftR(t(two_samples),8), 255)
mat_b <- bitwAnd(t(two_samples),255)
two_samples_flat <- array(c(mat_r, mat_g, mat_b))
arr <- array(two_samples_flat, dim=c(4,4,3,2))
data <- aperm(arr, c(4,1,2,3))
data[1,,,]
#> , , 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    0    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0    0
#> [3,]    1    1    1    1
#> [4,]    1    1    1    1
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    0    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0    0
#> [4,]    0    0    0    0
#> 
#> , , 3
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    1    1    0    0
#> [2,]    1    1    0    0
#> [3,]    1    1    0    0
#> [4,]    1    1    0    0
```

However, bit functions return flat vectors  and the modifying the dimension afterwards does not allow correct slicing of the multidimensional array. My expected dimension and output (one sample shown) are shown below

```
> dim(data)
2 4 4 3

> data[1,,,]
, , 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] 
 [1,]  0    0    1    1
 [2,]  0    0    1    1 
 [3,]  0    0    1    1
 [4,]  0    0    1    1

, , 2

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] 
 [1,]  1    1    1    1
 [2,]  1    1    1    1
 [3,]  0    0    0    0
 [4,]  0    0    0    0

, , 3

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] 
 [1,]  1    2    3    4
 [2,]  5    6    7    8
 [3,]  9    10   11   12
 [4,]  13   14   15   16
```

So, my question is, how can I prepare a multidimensional array from a matrix so that I can use with CNN. If I get this right, I can use `array_reshape` to reshape it to be used for dense layer network: `array_reshape(data, c(num_of_samples, width*height*3))`